# Disappearing images when loading the browser with grid and grid ends up with extra spacing on right side

Tags: jquery, css, sass

```
jQuery ( function ( $ ) {

    var offset = $('.grid-container').length + 1; 
    var itemsToLoad = 5; 
    var getDataUrl = '/data';
    var wall = new freewall("#freewall");

    imagesLoaded('#freewall', function(){

        wall.reset({
                    selector: '.grid-container',
                    animate: false,
                    cellW: 255,
                    cellH: 'auto',
                    fixSize: 1,
                    gutterX: 15, 
                    gutterY: 15, 
                    onResize: function() {
                        wall.fitWidth();
                        wall.refresh();
                    }
                });

                wall.fitWidth();

                var images = wall.container.find('.grid-container');
                            var length = images.length;
                            images.css({visibility: 'hidden'});
                            images.find('img').load(function() {
                                -- length;
                                if (!length) {
                                    setTimeout(function() {
                                        images.css({visibility: 'visible'});
                                        wall.fitWidth();
                                    }, 505);
                                }
                            });

         $('.pagination a').click(function(){

            loadNextPage();

        });

    });



    function loadNextPage() {


        $.ajax({
            url: getDataUrl,
            type: 'GET',
            data: {
                max: itemsToLoad,
                offset: offset
            },
            dataType: 'json',

            success: function( data ){
                _.each( data.items, function(item, index) {

                    var tempBlock = can.view( '/views/grid.ejs', { item: item });
                    wall.appendBlock( tempBlock );

                });

                imagesLoaded('#freewall', function(){
                    wall.refresh();
                    wall.fitWidth();

                });

            },
            error: function(error) {
                console.log( error)
            }
        });
    }
    $(window).trigger("resize");
});
```

SASS

```
 #freewall .grid-container{
    width: 255px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #DEDEDE;
    float: left;


    &.init {

        opacity: 0 !important;
    }

    p{
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }

    .title{
        color: #222;
        font-size: 17px;
        font-family: 'minion pro', serif;
        font-style: normal;
        font-weight: 400;
    }
    .owner{
        color: #666;
        font-size: 11px;
    }

    .info{
        padding: $padding*1.5px $padding*1.6px;
        float: left;
    }

}

.freewall {
  margin: 15px;

}

.grid-tile img {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: block;
}
```

Why the images disappear when the browser loads the grid with images? The issue seems to lay with visibility: hidden. I am trying to follow the example: http://vnjs.net/www/project/freewall/example/pinterest-layout.html -- this pinterest layout never has the extra spacing on right side when the images load. The problem is that in scss, the images would float to left when loading before the fitWidth() loads the layout that images fit in. How to eliminate the issue of extra spacing on right side or follow exactly same as pinterest - http://vnjs.net/www/project/freewall/example/pinterest-layout.html?

Thanks for the help

HTML

```
<div class="pure-u bdy-content des-content grid">
<div id="freewall" class="freewall">

        <div class="grid-container">
            <div class="grid-tile">
                <a class="overlay" href="http://www.afranko.com/">
                </a>
                <img src="http://www.afranko.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/0e87807b76a1045fae54eb59117e45fa.jpg" width="100%" />
            </div>

            <div class="info">

                <p class="title">Test</p>
                <p class="owner">Kitty</p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="grid-container">
            <div class="grid-tile">
                <a class="overlay" href="http://www.afranko.com/">
                </a>
                <img src="http://www.afranko.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/0e87807b76a1045fae54eb59117e45fa.jpg" width="100%" />
            </div>

            <div class="info">

                <p class="title">Test</p>
                <p class="owner">Kitty</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="grid-container">
            <div class="grid-tile">
                <a class="overlay" href="http://www.afranko.com/">
                </a>
                <img src="http://www.afranko.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/0e87807b76a1045fae54eb59117e45fa.jpg" width="100%" />
            </div>

            <div class="info">

                <p class="title">Test</p>
                <p class="owner">Kitty</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="grid-container">
            <div class="grid-tile">
                <a class="overlay" href="http://www.afranko.com/">
                </a>
                <img src="http://www.afranko.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/0e87807b76a1045fae54eb59117e45fa.jpg" width="100%" />
            </div>

            <div class="info">

                <p class="title">Test</p>
                <p class="owner">Kitty</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="grid-container">
            <div class="grid-tile">
                <a class="overlay" href="http://www.afranko.com/">
                </a>
                <img src="http://www.afranko.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/0e87807b76a1045fae54eb59117e45fa.jpg" width="100%" />
            </div>

            <div class="info">

                <p class="title">Test</p>
                <p class="owner">Kitty</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="grid-container">
            <div class="grid-tile">
                <a class="overlay" href="http://www.afranko.com/">
                </a>
                <img src="http://www.afranko.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/0e87807b76a1045fae54eb59117e45fa.jpg" width="100%" />
            </div>

            <div class="info">

                <p class="title">Test</p>
                <p class="owner">Kitty</p>
            </div>
        </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Can you post your markup (with dummy images) so that we have a complete example to play with?

Comment: @KatieK ok will post the markup soon but fyi its dynamic in grail template so it will display the number of images.